# Stripe, Stripe Payments, Connect, Linked Account, Split Payment

Tags: laravel, vue.js, stripe-payments

I'm onboarding new users into our platform using Stripe.

Firstly I'm creating account in Stripe

```
$this->stripe->accounts->create([
                'type' => 'express',
                'country' => 'US',
                'email' => $user->email,
                'capabilities' => [
                    'card_payments' => ['requested' => true],
                    'transfers' => ['requested' => true],
                ],
            ]);
```

Secondly I'm trying to link this account to our platform

```
return $this->stripe->accountLinks->create(
        [
            'account' => $id,
            'refresh_url' => 'xyz/stripe/onboard',
            'return_url' => 'xyz',
            'type' => 'account_onboarding',
        ]
    );
```

Then I have response with link to express onboard and everything is OK.

The problem occurs when I have already created account in Stripe connected with given email address.

I logged into Stripe in onboard process with found account (because email was already in theirs platform) which is fully configured and onboard process was finished.

This newly created account in step 1 which ID I'm storing in our database is Linked Account.

When I'm trying to create paymentIntents i receive error:
*Your destination account needs to have at least one of the following capabilities enabled: transfers, legacy_payments*

So this newly created and linked account isn't connected with account (already created  before onboard) which I logged into?

How I can link those two accounts? Because after successful login they redirect me into 'refresh_url'.

I want to split payment, so I need this second account to transfer $.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is referring to the connected account's capabilities[1]. As the error says, you need to get the account enabled for `transfers` to be able to designate it as the destination for a destination charge.

To fix this, you can request this capability for the account if it has not been already[2] and direct your user to fill out the required info through stripe's onboarding. You may also request capabilities when creating your accounts if you know they will be needed[3] in which case collecting data for them will be part of the initial onboarding flow.

[1] https://stripe.com/docs/connect/account-capabilities#transfers

[2] https://stripe.com/docs/connect/account-capabilities#requesting-unrequesting

[3] https://stripe.com/docs/connect/account-capabilities#creating

Comment: I'm not asking why I got this error because I can easily check documentation and everything is there.

I'm asking why when I'm Linking Account from onboarding process when user login as existing Stripe account I don't have any response from Stripe with this account ID. So If I want to make a split payment I can't attach this account because I have only ID from step 1 - newly created account but never used because I logged with existing acc.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. What do you mean by "I don't have any response from Stripe with this account ID"? Are you saying you aren't getting some webhook event that you are expecting to get?

Comment: And what do you mean that you need to "attach" the account? What are you trying to do and what info other than the account ID do you need here?

Comment: I need to link this account to our platform because we will make split payments. So I need this account ID to transfer money there. When I'm going into onboarding page I'm creating user (account) (and I have this account id). But if someone will login with existing account after successful login it redirect me to our platform without any info about this account which I used to login. So onboard process is finished and I don't have account id to this account which I used to login, just account id from step 1 which was account creation - like in a docs